# Help me solve this limit problem

Tags: calculus

Hey can someone help me solve this? Thanks

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 11 \pi/2} \frac{\cos (11 x)}{x - 11 \pi/2}$$

Comment: Enclose it in dollar signs..

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the formatting; please verify that it's correct. Can you please share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=\cos(11x)$. Note that $f(11\pi/2)=0$.

Thus we are looking for 
$$\lim_{x\to11\pi/2}\frac{f(x)-f(11\pi/2)}{x-11\pi/2}.$$
By definition, this is $f'(11\pi/2)$. Calculate the derivative using the ordinary rules of differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\displaystyle x-\dfrac{11\pi}2=u$

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac{11\pi}2}\left(\frac{\cos11x}{x-\dfrac{11\pi}2}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to0}\left(\frac{\cos\left[11\left(u+\dfrac{11\pi}2\right)\right]}u\right)$$

$$=\lim_{u\to0}\left(\frac{\cos\left(11u+\dfrac{\pi}2\right)}u\right)$$

$$=-11\lim_{u\to0}\left(\frac{\sin11u}{11u}\right)$$ as $\cos\left(\frac\pi2+y\right)=-\sin y$